# Multiple delete operation in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to make some tables empty if a stored procedure runs but I couldn't do that. What I did is

```
create proc MakeEmpty   ()
as
begin
  delete from table1
  delete from table2
 delete from table3
end
```

Comment: What happens when you run that stored procedure? The SQL looks fine.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MakeEmpty, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: your tables might still be locked. this may just been the one row that is being inserted if and insert operation is running during the call.

Comment: try and use semi colons for each line.

Comment: if I declare a variable between parantheses it works

Comment: Don't use the parentheses if you don't have a parameter...I'll add a note in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `truncate` instead and remove the `()` like this:

```
create proc MakeEmpty
as
begin
    truncate table table1
    truncate table table2
    truncate table table3
end
```

Comment: +1 - but be aware that truncate won't be available if foreign key constraints are defined on the tables.

Comment: OF course this whole thing should be in a try catch block and a transaction, so everything is rolled back if one of the statements fails. Never do more than one insert/update/delete (truncate counts asa delte) in a proc without transaction processing.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

**1** - Those parentheses should only be used if you are declaring a parameter for the procedure.  If there is no param they are unneeded.

**2** - If you want to empty the tables, then you should use `TRUNCATE` - it's minimally logged and is basically a meta-operation instead of a row-by-row delete.

You will need to clarify about what's not working, but something like this should do the trick:

```
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 from DatabaseName.sys.Tables WHERE Name = 'Table1')
TRUNCATE TABLE Databasename.dbo.Table1

...repeat for other tables...

END
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove the `(` and `)`

```
create proc MakeEmpty
as
begin
   delete from table1;
   delete from table2;
   delete from table3;
end
```

but make sure `table2` and `table3` does not reference `table1` and `table3` does not reference `table2`